# How do I get tab spaces to work in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Is it possible to get CKEditor to recognize tab as a feature inside the editor, especially when in source code mode? Right now, when I hit the tab key, the cursor goes to the next field on the page.

I'd like to get the tab character working so CKEditor can work more like a code editor in which I can format my markup with tab spaces.

I'd really appreciate any help I can get with this.

I'm using CKEDitor 4.0.1

Or, perhaps this feature is supported in one of the newer versions of CKEditor?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://get-simple.info/forums/showthread.php?tid=1347

Comment: Thanks rvighne. That did the trick! I added `config.tabSpaces = 4;` to my config.js file. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This link might help: http://get-simple.info/forums/showthread.php?tid=1347

Basically, just add

```
config.tabSpaces = 4; // or some other value
```

to `config.js` and every time <kbd>Tab</kbd> is hit, you get that number of spaces.

Comment: That works but the editor doesn't allow "real" tabs. For example, when you hit the same number of tabs on different lines containing text the two lines are not correctly aligned (even when using space/back-space).

Comment: Should be noted that this requires installing tab plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/tab

Answer (score 1):

The code is `config.tabSpaces = 4;` if you are saving to config.js. If you are setting configurations inside the file, the code will be as follows:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    tabSpaces: 4
});
```

it should be noticed, as Kamil Sama commented in rvighne answer, that this requires the tab plugin: [tab plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/tab)

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea name="text_note" id="text_note"> </textarea> 


 <!-- tabSpaces:4 add this in your script like as bellow code.-->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('text_note',{tabSpaces:4});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using inline element, you can use like this

var editor2 = CKEDITOR.inline( 'your div id', {
tabSpaces : 5,
});